# JetBrain IDE project creation trouble

Tags: java

I was creating a new project in JetBrain IDE (IdeaIC-2016.1.2). While creating a new project SDk i choose the JDK option and when i want to select the path i was looking for JDK in Java folder but instead there were only JRE 1.8.0_31 and JRE 1.8.0_91 instead of JDK version? What could be the problem?

Comment: You probably downloaded a JRE instead of a JDK. You can download a JDK here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: JRE = Java RunTime Environment and JDK = Java Development Kit. 

Ideally, you need a Development Kit for your development tasks, which then needs a RunTime Environment to compile,build and run.

Clearly, having a RE is not sufficient for the overall purpose of using an IDE.

Comment: I had downloaded the software directly from the website (the community version) and which one to download from the oracle website 8u91 or 8u92?